# Кросс-компиляция Qt5 для Windows из под Linux

Tags: linux, qt, кросс-компиляция

Использую MXE. Следую этим инструкциям https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591

Мои действия:

```
git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git 
cd mxe
make qtbase
```

В конце компиляции qtbase выводится ошибка:

```
    Failed to build package qtbase for target i686-w64-mingw32.static!
------------------------------------------------------------
or compile needed modules into the library.
ERROR: Feature 'sql-psql' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.psql' failed.
make[1]: *** [build-only-qtbase_i686-w64-mingw32.static] Ошибка 3
make[1]: Выход из каталога `/home/homa/setup/mxe'
real    3m24.062s
user    3m12.616s
sys 0m13.024s
------------------------------------------------------------
[log]      /home/homa/setup/mxe/log/qtbase_i686-w64-mingw32.static

make: *** [/home/homa/setup/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/installed/qtbase] Ошибка 1
```

Насколько я понимаю, он требует postgresql, но мне это не нужно.
Зависимости http://mxe.cc/#requirements уже установлены. ОС Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Ну вам английским по-серому написали, что затребована фича, а возможности включить нет. Перед `make qtbase` разберитесь с тем, как и какие фичи вы включаете.

Comment: А можно ли как-то эту фичу не требовать? Как они включаются?

Comment: так это вроде в makefile прописано

Comment: перед сборкой нужно его через configur прогнать. там был файлик в котором указывается что собирать а что нет

Comment: Собрал все. Просто скачал исходники более новой версии.